# What should be in /usr/local/bin in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a laptop running linux, and I've installed various bits and pieces into /usr/local/bin. Some software has created subdirectories (e.g. firefox & blender), some has just gone into /usr/local/bin.

Is this right, that software creates subdirectories in /usr/local/bin, or would it be better to create a subdirectory in /usr/local?

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local` is a good place to deposit software when you install them from compilation (`./configure && make && make install`). This is the default location for virtually every software compiled and installed by hand.

Comment: when i compile software, it will correctly put the binaries in /usr/local/bin, libs in /usr/local/lib, etc. but what about when i download a precompiled package such as firefox, which when i extract it it creates a 'firefox' directory?

Comment: In such cases, the precompiled software is *self-contained* into that directory. You can put it wherever you like, while the most common are `/usr/local/firefox` and `/opt/firefox`. Just add some symlinks to the executable file, so it can be found in your `$PATH` (or change the `$PATH` to include these extra directories). See also: http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-9-Manual/ref-guide/s1-filesystem-fhs.html

Answer (score 0):

All software unique to a given box go under usr/local. The binaries go under bin, lbraries go under lib, config files under etc, and so on.
So
It is not right, that software creates subdirectories in /usr/local/bin, and it is not right to create a subdirectory in /usr/local.
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY

Comment: so when i download firefox and it extracts to a 'firefox' directory where do i put it?